# Python Webdriver how to find dynamic parameter on web table

Tags: jquery, python, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Python > webdriver

I want the method to get an id > locate the row on the web table > click on the name of the row

I have:

- table with the ids (in red - to find) and name (in blue - to click on)

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSNW7.jpg)

[HTML of the table where I want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfFki.jpg)

- method the gets parameter 'list_id' = id number in the platform (ex. 813231) to locate the list

In the code below:

1. I defined the table on the web page
2. 'customer' - found the row contains "813231"
3. clicked on the first columns (because the id include on each html column name)

That's the closest I've got but far from what I want.

How can I find the parameter 'list_id' and click on the text on the third column?

** attached the screenshot in the links above.

```html
        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='body-container']/table")
        customer = table.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '813231')]")
        customer.click()
```

Comment: I have read this question 5 times and still can't understand it. Could you rephrase?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!   I just edited the question, hope it'll be more clear.